# Can we use extern keyword with typedef datatype in header file?

Tags: c, stack, static-libraries, typedef, extern

I want to implement stack and its functions using static libraries in c.  But even after declaring STACK in header file using extern i am getting errors that STACK is not declared.I have declared stack in a separate stack_1.c file and want other functions like push, pop etc to access this stack.Is it possible to do so?

- List item

  inside stack_main.c

  ```
  #define MAX 5
  #include "lib.h"

  void push(int, STACK *);
  int pop(STACK *);
  void display(STACK *);

  int main()
  {
      int flag,ele,show;

      STACK s;
      s.top=-1;

      while(1)
      {
          printf("Enter 1:push 2:pop 3:display 4:exit\n");
          scanf("%d",&flag);

          switch(flag)
          {
             case 1:
              printf("Enter ele\n");
              scanf("%d",&ele);
              push(ele,&s);
              break;
  ```

  inside lib.h

  ```
  extern STACK;
  int main();
  void push(int , STACK *);
  int pop(STACK *);
  void display(STACK *);
  ```

  inside push.c

  ```
  #include "lib.h"       
  void push(int ele, STACK* a)
  {
       if(a->top!= MAX-1)
       {
            a->top++;
            a->stk[a->top]=ele;
       }
  }
  ```

  inside stack_1.c

  ```
  #define MAX 5
  #include "lib.h"

  typedef struct {

          int stk[MAX] ;
          int top;       
  }STACK;
  ```

  ERRORS:

  > ani@ani-VirtualBox:~/Documents/ostl/week4$ gcc -c stack_main.c stack_1.c push.c pop.c display.c
  >       In file included from stack_main.c:4:0:
  >       lib.h:1:8: warning: type defaults to ‘int’ in declaration of ‘STACK’ [-Wimplicit-int]
  >        extern STACK;
  >               ^~~~~
  >       lib.h:3:17: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘STACK’
  >        void push(int , STACK *);
  >                        ^~~~~
  >       lib.h:4:9: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘STACK’
  >        int pop(STACK *);
  >                ^~~~~
  >       lib.h:5:14: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘STACK’
  >        void display(STACK *);
  >                     ^~~~~
  >       stack_main.c:8:16: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘STACK’
  >        void push(int, STACK *);
  >                       ^~~~~
  >       stack_main.c:9:9: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘STACK’
  >        int pop(STACK *);
  >                ^~~~~
  >       stack_main.c:10:14: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘STACK’
  >        void display(STACK *);
  >                     ^~~~~
  >       stack_main.c: In function ‘main’:
  >       stack_main.c:16:11: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘s’
  >            STACK s;
  >                  ^
  >       stack_main.c:17:5: error: ‘s’ undeclared (first use in this function)
  >            s.top=-1;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> .I have declared stack in a separate stack_1.c file and want other functions like push, pop etc to access this stack.

No, you will have to add the definition of the type `STACK` in a header file which is included in `stack_main.c` and `push.c`.

Easiest option is to move the definition of the type `STACK` to the header file `lib.h`

What you can also do is to define the structure in the `stack_1.c` and the typedef in the header file. This can hide your internal workings of the STACK, from the external world. However in your case, i would go with the first approach.

e.g. in stack_1.c (or preferably in another header file)

```
struct stack1{

    int stk[MAX] ;
    int top;  
};
```

and in lib.h

```
typedef struct stack1 STACK;
```

Answer (score 4):

The compiler doesn't know what `STACK` is when you have the external declaration. And you can't use `extern` type-aliases anyway.

But you can solve it just the way that the standard C library does with the `FILE` structure:

```
typedef struct stack_struct STACK;
```

As long as the users of your library only use pointers to `STACK` (i.e. `STACK *`) then they don't need the structure definition itself. This makes the stack an [opaque data type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_data_type).

Then in your implementation you simply have

```
struct stack_struct
{
    // Your structure...
};
```

in a private header file that you include in your implementation source files. And it's important that you put the structure definition in a header file, having the structure in a source file makes it available to that single source file only.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting that error because the compiler is not able to understand what is "STACK" while compiling stack_main.c

The "extern" keyword is not for the type but for variables. i.e. If you have defined global a variable in a .c file and want to use in another .c file, then you have to tell second .c file that there is a variable already defined in another .c file and just use that variable using "extern" keyword.

So to fix the errors, you need to define STACK type in a .h file and include that .h file in both the .c file.